# Objects in JSON array. Store each of them to ArrayList

Tags: java, json, libgdx

So I have this kind of JSON.(Retrived via ASP.NET Webservice).

```
    d: [
{
    __type: webservice+Info
    name: Bobo
    score: 55
}
{
    __type: webservice+Info
    name: Mickey
    score: 26
}
{
    __type: webservice+Info
    name: KxKnight
    score: 85
}
]
```

I already have a class which will hold it's own particular value (name and score). Now I just want to save them to ArrayList. I'm doing with LIBGDX JSON Library.

Any help appriciated.

EDIT:

I've tried with

```
ArrayList<TopScore> list1 = json.fromJson(ArrayList.class, TopScore.class, json);
```

But I'm getting NPE in line above.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:912)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:720)
    at com.mygdx.game.Networking2$1.handleHttpResponse(Networking2.java:161)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.net.NetJavaImpl$1.run(NetJavaImpl.java:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What code do you have so far, and what's the problem with it?

Comment: Are you initializing `list1` before this?

Comment: No, since "fromJson" method uses a reflection and returns full instance of ArrayList. The NPE comes from "fromJson" method and not "list1" instance.

Comment: Does it work with json that uses double-quotes like `{"example":"value"} ` ? The json parser may be strict on that. Also don't forget that libgdx is open-source, so you can actually debug that stacktrace and see where it fails.

Comment: The thing you are describing as a JSON array is not valid JSON. The objects in the array are not comma separated and the fields and values are not in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The json String that you're passing in is null.

If you follow the stack trace you'll see it's originating from com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json line 912.

Check the code that populates the json String, and make sure it populates it with a non-null value.